# How to make a moving platform with Unity Tilemap?

Tags: unity, tilemap, platformer, moving-platforms

I am trying to make  a 2D level of a game and want to know how to move a specific tile left and right.

All the level is designed on a single Tilemap. I want to move one platform left and right. How would I do that?

[image: Platforms in Tilemap]

Comment: You should use a GameObject with scripts for things that are interactive. TileMaps are best used for things that don't move and don't have interactivity beyond simple static collision.

Comment: @Romen If you posted an answer showing such a script and how to set up its sprites to match the tiles, I'd upvote it.